# Difference between createQuery and find in Morphia?

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

The documentation says:

```
/** Returns a new query bound to the collection (a specific DBCollection) **/
<T> Query<T> createQuery(Class<T> collection);

/** Find all instances by type **/
<T> Query<T> find(Class<T> clazz)
```

Both return a `Query<T>` object. The results are equal. What is the difference?

Answer (score 2):

They are identical.

Looking at DataSourceImpl.java, it is just a wrapper for createQuery.

```
// DatastoreImpl.java

@Override
public <T> Query<T> find(final Class<T> clazz) {
    return createQuery(clazz);
}
```